# How to show dynamic content in cluetip?

Tags: jquery, .net, cluetip

I am using cluetip to show a tooltip when a user hovers over a link in my aspx page. I want this cluetip to show content from the database. I don't know how to do it.

My code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {$('a.title').cluetip
({   splitTitle: '|' });
    });
```

Aspx code:
    `<a class="title" href="#" title="This is the title|Work Experience">Previous Exp</a>`

I would want to get the data from the database in the content of the cluetip.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a demo on the cluetip plugin website that suggests this syntax for ajax-based cluetips:

```
<a class="basic" href="ajax.html" rel="ajax.html">
```

Yours would be:

```
<a class="title" rel="ajax.php" href="#" title="This is the title|Work Experience">Previous Exp</a>
```

where ajax.php is replaced with an asp page that returns what you want to display in the cluetip.

Edit: You also have to remove the split title functionality.

```
<a class="title" rel="ajax.php" href="#" title="Work Experience">Previous Exp</a>


$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.title').cluetip();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to show the content in the cluetip based on the users data.Hence, instead of using a 'rel' attribute, is there a way to query the database using a <div> tag or by some other means?

Comment: no, you have to do it through the rel attribute. http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ keep in mind you can pass an id through the url in the rel attribute, such as `rel="ajax.php?id=77256"`

Comment: Thanks. It worked when the link is clicked. But, on hover, I am still unable to generate dynamic content..

Comment: You have to remove the split title functionality, that make's it ignore the rel attribute.